# Pig JSON conversion

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm using pig 0.12.1 version. I need to convert each row into JSON string then i have save this string in HBase. I tried with several ways...

First way is use JsonStorage. This will store as a json file. Then we have to read it back to get json string. But this involved a write and read operation to hdfs.

```
STORE formatted_data INTO 'formated_json.json' USING JsonStorage();
```

Second way i wrote a user defined function in java and build as jar, added this jar to hadoop. It's also working fine.

My question is, can't we achieve this by Pig Scripts without this much complex.